# Regex Tables how to match?

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I like to return the strings in this table

```
<tr class="rowodd" onclick="window.location.href='/portal/offers/show/entityId/32114';">
  <td>01.10.2009</td>
   <td>AN09551</td>
     <td>[2009132] Ich bin Un.&nbsp;<a href="/portal/clients/show/entityId/762350"><myimsrc="/img/bullet_go.pngs" alt="" title="Kundenakte aufrufen"></a></td>
   <td class="number" title="7.500,00Â&nbsp;â‚¬">7.500,00Â&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Entwurf</td>
     </tr>
```

I tryed Also this:

```
#<tr>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?</tr>#s
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Reformatted to expose the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use that many inexplicit non-greedy expressions like `.*?`. Though they do what you want, they come with a lot of backtracking and thus make your whole expression inefficient. Especially when you use so many of them.

Try to be as explicit as possible:

```
#<tr\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>\s*
    <td\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
    <td\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
    <td\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
    <td\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
    <td\b(?:[^"'>]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
</tr\s*>#sx
```

But as you see, this is a mess.

You should better use an HTML parser like the one of [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument). Then you can query the elements with XPath as Brian Agnew suggested. That’s way more reliable and comfortable than regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks it worrked $pattern = '#<tr\b(?:[^\"\'>]*|\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\')*>\s*
  <td\b(?:[^\"\'>]*|\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
  <td\b(?:[^"\'>]*|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
  <td\b(?:[^"\'>]*|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
   <td\b(?:[^"\'>]*|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
  <td\b(?:[^"\'>]*|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*>((?:[^<]|(?!</td\s*>)<)*)</td\s*>\s*
  </tr\s*>#sx';

Answer (score 3):

As numerous people will/have pointed out, you're much better off using an HTML/XML parser for the above (like [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)). HTML isn't regular and there are numerous edge cases to code around if you use a regular expression.

Given that you just want to extract the text, perhaps XPath will help. An expression such as:

```
/tr/td/text()
```

may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$str = '<tr class="rowodd" onclick="window.location.href=\'/portal/offers/show/entityId/32114\';">
  <td>
    01.10.2009
  </td>
  <td>
    AN09551
  </td>
  <td>
    [2009132] Ich bin Un. <a href="/portal/clients/show/entityId/762350">
    <myimsrc="/img/bullet_go.pngs" alt="" title="Kundenakte aufrufen"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="number" title="7.500,00">
    7.500,00
  </td>
  <td>
    Entwurf
  </td>
</tr>';
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('td') as $element) {
  echo trim($element->innertext) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
01.10.2009
AN09551
[2009132] Ich bin Un. <a href="/portal/clients/show/entityId/762350">
    <myimsrc="/img/bullet_go.pngs" alt="" title="Kundenakte aufrufen"></a>
7.500,00
Entwurf
```

Comment: Call to undefined function  str_get_html()
is it simple_html_parser?

Comment: but its a html page so there maybealot more td's. 
So to find all td's isnt a good idea

Comment: Yes, str_get_html() is defined in simple_html_parser

Comment: You can get certain (or just one) tr's based on a given attribute and get the td's from it. Read the documentation, it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

isn’t [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) an option?

it will strip all tags and only leave the text between the tags. it strips attributes too though

in your case this would result in:

```
  01.10.2009
   AN09551
     [2009132] Ich bin Un. 
   7.500,00 € 
    Entwurf
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise with a regexp you could use this (with multi-line option):

```
(?:\<td[^\>]*?\>([^\<]*?)\</td\>)+
```

But as pointed out by @Brian Agnew, this is just nowhere as good as an xml/html parser...

Comment: Worket like nothing else 
#(?:\<td[^\>]*?\>([^\<]*?)\</td\>)+#siU

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PHP world, there's preg_match_all which makes it much easier than do in JS.

```
$ptn = "/<\s*td[^>]*>([^<^>]*)</;
preg_match_all($ptn, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Test the result in [Preg Tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm)