# Simple html dom - how get dt/dd elements to array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, simple-html-dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get data only from html table used preg_match_all in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057574/get-data-only-from-html-table-used-preg-match-all-in-php)

HTML:

```
   <div class="table">
       <dl>
            <dt>ID:</dt>
            <dd>632991</dd>
            <dt>Type:</dt>
            <dd>NEW</dd>
            <dt>Body Type:</dt>
            <dd>Compact</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

What's is the best way to get this using simple_html_dom in PHP:

PHP:

```
$option = array(
    'id' => 632991,
    'Type' => 'NEW',
    'Body Type' => 'Compact'
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use XPath:

[Getting DOM elements by classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-class-name)

[Get Element ByTag Name](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

[Using PHP to get DOM Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144061/using-php-to-get-dom-element)

Here are a lot of posts on Stackoverflow. Use the search here.

**Edit:**

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div class="table">
       <dl class="list">
            <dt>ID:</dt>
            <dd>632991</dd>
            <dt>Type:</dt>
            <dd>NEW</dd>
            <dt>Body Type:</dt>
            <dd>Compact</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>');

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('dl');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump(getArray($node));
}

function getArray($node) { 
    $array = false; 

    if ($node->hasAttributes()) { 
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) { 
            $array[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($node->hasChildNodes()) { 
        if ($node->childNodes->length == 1) { 
            $array[$node->firstChild->nodeName] = $node->firstChild->nodeValue; 
        } else { 
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode) { 
                if ($childNode->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE) { 
                    $array[$childNode->nodeName][] = getArray($childNode); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $array; 
} 
?>
```

The function getArray is from php.net

Comment: Those links are a bit too generic and RTFM, none of them pertains to a `<table>` example.

Comment: Under the last Link is a complete example. And yes its a short hint. When you want to learn something you should think about and try it out or not?

Comment: We already have a few thousand cursory answers on this topic, as you remarked yourself.

Comment: Hey i'am not so fast ;) when i post some code it should be correct. But the most of the informations are on the related sites.